Azure SQL Database connection string in Azure Kubernetes Services
I have created some helm charts which deploy Azure resources using the Azure Service Operator. My main question is how can I retrieve the ConnectionString from the newly created Azure SQL Database to pass it to a service which may consume it as a Secret?
Should it be part of the Helm template to create a secret based on the inputs or is there another approach how to handle it?.
Many thanks

are you facing any error?

To be honest I am looking for Best Practices I am not sure if generating the connection string as part of the helm template and storing as secret is the best way?

Can you check this once?

To retrieve the Connection String from the newly created Azure SQL Database to pass it to a service, you can follow the below steps-
Assuming you have a SQL server and a DB created

Retrieve the connection string
CONNECTION_STRING=$(az sql db show-connection-string --server arkoazuresqlserver --name myazuresqldb --client ado.net --output tsv)

Encode the connection string to base64
BASE64_CONNECTION_STRING=$(echo -n "$CONNECTION_STRING" | base64)

Create a secret
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: azuresql-connection-string
  namespace: default
type: Opaque
data:
  connectionString: <base64-encoded-connection-string>


You can verify the same-

Now if you want to consume this in your application deployment then
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: myapp:latest
        env:
        - name: SQL_CONNECTION_STRING
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: azuresql-connection-string
              key: connectionString

If you are going via helm approach then you can edit your template/secret.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: azuresql-connection-string
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
type: Opaque
data:
  connectionString: {{ .Values.connectionString | b64enc | quote }}

and update your values.yaml with the connection string
connectionString: "Server=tcp:arkoazuresqlserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=myazuresqldb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=arko;Password=myStrongPassword!123;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"


and then redeploy the helm chart.
